# Unit test of HTML5 file upload

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to do JavaScript unit test for uploading a file using the HTML 5 File API?

For example I have the code:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function fileSelectHandler(e) {
       var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
       // at this point, files is a FileList object
   }

   var fileselect = document.getElementById("fileselect");
   fileselect.addEventListener("change", fileSelectHandler, false);
</script>
```

So I want to automate this with JavaScript, so I can unit test it. So I need to fire the change event, and pass the files somehow. In the end, each file should be a HTML 5 File object, with a custom path that I want.

Comment: You can't set the value of `file` input with JavaScript, to do this you'd need a browser extension of some kind.  However, why are you trying to test the functionality of the browser's input, why not just have a file object as part of the test?

Comment: Robert, my 'complicated' code starts with having the files variable, which is a FileList. How do I make that FileList being a list of File objects that point to actual files on harddisk ?

Comment: I already said that you can't, but even if you could, if your test to select a file with the `input` element failed, what would that prove about your application?  Are you planning to send C++ patches to the various browser vendors?

Comment: My code is much longer than this, and it continues to work with the File objects, parse the files, upload them through AJAX POST call to some server, etc. So my aim is the rest of my javascript code, not the selection of a file.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it. I also wanted to test my upload function that would accept a File or FileList as one of its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of test is not a unit test, it is an integration test

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

https://www.guru99.com/integration-testing.html

There are a lot of frameworks for integration test that can do that task easily, like https://webdriver.io/ or https://www.selenium.dev/ and more

Try to sort your tests in corresponding tool and life will be better!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help but how about using iMacros for firefox? You can record a macro that does everything you want and then just run it as often as you want. It's really easy to use and works for me for almost all of my UI testing.

[iMacros firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/?src=collection&collection_id=da0ecd99-2289-7ab0-7d57-e7c489c845c3)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using `jest-fetch-mock`

```
describe('fileSelectHandler', () => {
  it('should handle file upload', async () => {
    const file = new File(['hello'], 'hello.txt', { type: 'text/plain' });
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.files = [file];

    const mockResponse = { status: 200 };
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(mockResponse));

    await fileSelectHandler({ target: { files: input.files } });

    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: expect.any(FormData),
    });
  });
});
```